# Iterate a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using a model to detect the sentiments of a data frame, currently this is the code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base- sentiment")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm- roberta-base-sentiment")
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base-sentiment")


  text = "i hate you :/"
  encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
  output = model(**encoded_input)
  scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
  scores = softmax(scores)

  ranking = np.argsort(scores)
  ranking = ranking[::-1]
  for i in range(scores.shape[0]):
     l = config.id2label[ranking[i]]
     s = scores[ranking[i]]
     print(f"{i+1}) {l} {np.round(float(s), 4)}")
```

Output

1. Negative 0.9468
2. Neutral 0.0379
3. Positive 0.0153

I am trying to adapt the code above to evaluate the column "final_tweet" of my dataset. So far I have tried to do with the following lines:

```
 text = df["final_tweet"]

 encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
 output = model(**encoded_input)
 scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
 scores = softmax(scores)
```

I would like to iterate over my column final_tweet but I do not exactly how can I do this.

Comment: can you explain more what you're trying to do? you have a for loop over the length of the array in your code, why does that not solve the problem? what do you want to do when iterating?

Comment: This is the issue that I have "Text input must be str(single example), List[str] " I am trying to evaluate each row of my column "final_tweet" and get the sentiment for each row, not on ky for one string as the example

Comment: If you're getting a specific error please add the full stack trace to your question and simplify your question to focus on debugging the issue. From your code block it's really hard for us to tell what's going on. Ideally please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate over a column of a pandas dataframe you can use `.map`.

First, write a function `my_predict(tweet)` that will take a tweet and return the sentiment (could be a list). Then you can simply do `df["final_tweet"].map(my_predict)`. This is generic and will work with any framework. However, you should not do this, as it's extremely inefficient.

---

If your dataset is small enough, you can predict it as a whole pretty much using your code

```py
docs = df["final_tweet"]

encoded_input = tokenizer(docs, return_tensors='pt')
output = model(**encoded_input)
scores = output.logits.softmax(dim=1).detach().numpy()  # need .logits?..
```

---

But when your dataset is large you'd want to do this in batches. Unfortunately huggingface is still figuring out what's the best way to do this, see this [discussion](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/13141).

Still, we can improve on "iterate over each tweet" or "run out of memory" by implementing a simple batched inference function.

```py
def _batch_split_for_inference(texts, batch_size):
    batches = []
    n_texts = len(texts)
    n_batches = n_texts//batch_size
    for i_batch in range(n_batches):
        i_from = i_batch*batch_size
        i_to = min((i_batch+1)*batch_size, n_texts)
        batches.append(texts[i_from:i_to])
    return batches

def predict_tweets_in_batched(tweets, batch_size):
    pred_batches = []
    for pred_texts_batch in _batch_split_for_inference(tweets, batch_size=batch_size):
        encoded_input = tokenizer(pred_texts_batch, return_tensors='pt')
        output = model(**encoded_input)
        scores = output.logits.softmax(dim=1).detach().numpy() 

    return np.vstack(scores)
```

---

Note, this is pretty much pseudo-code, you'll have to adapt it to your dataset, model, hardware etc.